# "Parameter is not valid" when using Image.fromStream method

Tags: sql-server, windows, varbinary

I am struggling for hours now with this issue.

```
If result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
  Dim path As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
  Dim img As Image = Image.FromFile(path)
  Using mStream As New MemoryStream()
    img.Save(mStream, img.RawFormat)
    Dim bArr As Byte() = mStream.ToArray()
  End Using
  Dim params As New List(Of SqlParameter)
  params.Add(New SqlParameter("@Image", bArr))
  CallSP("UpdateImageSP", params)
End If
```

This will actually update the database, in a varbinary column, with the value:
0x89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D49484452000004120000041208060000001258D9C6000000017352474200AECE1CE900000004

Time to retrieve the image & show it in a picturebox:

```
Dim dtIcon As DataTable = DataTableGet("getImageSP")
If dtIcon IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not dtIcon.Rows(0)("Image") Is DBNull.Value Then
  Dim imageData As Byte() = DirectCast(dtIcon.Rows(0)("Image"), Byte())
  If imageData.Length > 0 Then
    Using mStream As New MemoryStream(imageData)
      Dim x As Image = Image.FromStream(mStream) --<--ERROR HERE !!
    End Using
    PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = x
  End If
End If
```

The error is **"An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
Additional information: Parameter is not valid."**

I've tried several samples of code that I found, the result was always this one. Anyone knows what's the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image could be getting saved incorrectly when uploading to the database, or you could have an issue converting it back.

One thing I would do is declare the type of your byte array going to SQL:

```
params.Add(New SqlParameter("@Image", bArr, SqlDbType.VarBinary,-1))
```

When loading the image to the database, you are not using the data as an image type. It would be easier to get the binary data using File.ReadAllBytes:

```
Dim bArr As Byte()
bArr = File.ReadAllBytes(path)
```

Also, you can test to confirm that the saved data from the database looks correct by trying save it to disk instead of loading into a picturebox. If you cannot open it as an image there is something wrong with the saved data:

```
Dim stream As New FileStream([Some Test Path], FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
stream.Write(imageData, 0, imageData.Length)
stream.Close()
```

Comment: As soon as I specified the SqlDbType on the parameter everything started working! Thanks!

Comment: Also, image was being truncated because of UpdateImageSP @Image parameter being set as VarBinary(50) instead of VarBinary(MAX).

Answer (score 0):

Your first code snippet should not work. There is an error, because this code creates a scope block:

```
Using mStream As New MemoryStream()
    img.Save(mStream, img.RawFormat)
    Dim bArr As Byte() = mStream.ToArray()
End Using
```

Once that block is closed, the `bArr` array goes *out of scope* (note: not disposed. Just out of scope) when you use it later on:

```
 params.Add(New SqlParameter("@Image", bArr))
```

To fix it, either extend the scope block, or declare the `bArr` before the scope block:

```
If result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
     Dim path As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
     Dim img As Image = Image.FromFile(path)
     Dim bArr() As Byte
     Using mStream As New MemoryStream()
        img.Save(mStream, img.RawFormat)
        bArr = mStream.ToArray()
     End Using
     Dim params As New List(Of SqlParameter)
     params.Add(New SqlParameter("@Image", bArr))
     CallSP("UpdateImageSP", params)
End If
```

That this much works for you so far is an accident of not having garbage collection take place at the wrong time. I don't know that this will fix your issue, but you should still address it.

To more thoroughly test the issue from your question, I would temporarily change the method to keep your byte when you upload to the DB, so that you can compare it byte for byte to the array when you retrieve it back from the DB. Find and analyze any differences. If they are the same (this is what you're hoping for), it's time to move to the next step.

If I had to guess, though, I'd say the problem is using `img.RawFormat` when you save it to the memory stream, that somehow this is not the format you expect. In any case, you can you can side-step that whole issue by loading the byte array directly from the file:

```
If result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    Dim bArr As Byte() = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
    Dim params As New List(Of SqlParameter)
    params.Add(New SqlParameter("@Image", bArr))
    CallSP("UpdateImageSP", params)
End If
```

Finally, the return code again has the scope issue, where your `x` Image variable can potentially be collected in the that short two line space between when it goes out of scope and when you assign to the PictureBox:

```
Dim dtIcon As DataTable = DataTableGet("getImageSP")
If dtIcon IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not (dtIcon.Rows(0)("Image") Is DBNull.Value) Then
    Dim imageData As Byte() = DirectCast(dtIcon.Rows(0)("Image"), Byte())
    If imageData.Length > 0 Then
        Using mStream As New MemoryStream(imageData)
            PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(mStream) 
        End Using
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Sorry about these basic errors, I was too tired yesterday. Thank you!